# make a SQL query on some databases of the same server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a simple select query on several databases on the same server, the server has 104 databases where 52 have the same schema so that is 2 different schemas (this are being generated by equipment on production floor, is a mistake that I have to handle until the equipment vendor figures how to create a single database for each scheme).

So I have a query like

```
select * 
from TB_AOIResult 
where serialnumber = 'snx'
```

At first I use this, it retrieves the data, but also a lot of errors as several databases on the server do not have that table .

```
[exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ?;SELECT  *  FROM \[TB_AOIResult\] where barcode ="102564AG1710200018476"'
```

go][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB7Y4.png)

then

so far the only way that I have found is to declare all the 52 databases (at this moment, the machines will generate a new db per week) in this statement, that is severally impractical

```
declare @sql1 as VARCHAR(4000)
SET @sql1 ='IF ''?''IN(''KY_Result_201715'',''KY_Result_201714'',''KY_Result_201713'',''KY_Result_201712''[enter image description here][2])
            EXECUTE(''USE [?]
                      SELECT  *  FROM [TB_AOIResult] where barcode ="102564AG1710200018476" '')'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @sql1
```

Could someone help me and explain me if there is any other way to do this query in all the databases with the same schema and avoid to run in the ones that does not have the table, without write the name of each database?

Thanks

Comment: You could look at the system tables for that database to see if the table exists in a schmea, if it does execute if not skip that db.

Comment: Do all your databases have the same naming convention of KY_Result_ followed by four digit year followed by a . . .two digit day? Two digit incrementing number?

Comment: yes all my databases have the same name format  that is KY_Results_yearweek.

Comment: xQbert :pardon my ignorance , but look at the system tables implies that i have to make a statement where i write the database names and then modifiy that statement every week as they are added???,or there is a simple way to do that . i tried to put the query on the system tables as if exist do smething  and then a sp_foreachdb but the error was the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it as follows:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = 'USE ?; 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N''TB_AOIResult'') BEGIN SELECT * FROM TB_AOIResult where barcode like ''102564AG171020001847%'' END'

go
```